# op_cross_self - while making a new offer

Tags: operations, manageofferoperation, offer

What is `op_cross_self` error?
I can create offers for 2 Assets ( selling and buying ).

But when creating a reverse offer for same asset, it's throwing :

```
    { transaction: 'tx_failed', operations: [ 'op_cross_self' ] }
```

This is how i'm making an offer:

```
module.exports.makingOfferNativetoUSD = async (clientSK,amt,rate,cutDown) => {

  const client = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(clientSK);
  let rate_converted = parseFloat(rate).toFixed(7);
  let total_amt = parseFloat( parseFloat(amt).toFixed(7) * 
  (rate_converted)).toFixed(7);
  let USD = new StellarSdk.Asset('USD', source.publicKey());
  if(cutDown){
  rate_converted = parseFloat(rate_converted - 0.01).toFixed(7);
  }

  var op ={
    selling: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
    buying:  USD,
    amount: amt+"",
    price: rate_converted+"",
    offerId:0 
  }

 return server.loadAccount(client.publicKey())
    .then(function(account) {
      var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
      .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.changeTrust({
        asset: USD
      }))
        .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageOffer(op))
        .setTimeout(10000)
        .build();
      transaction.sign(StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(client.secret()));
      return server.submitTransaction(transaction);

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return err; 
    });

}
```

And creating another offer to accept it :

```
module.exports.sellRevOfferUSDtoNative = async (clientSK,amt,rate,cutDown) => {

  const client = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(clientSK);
  let USD = new StellarSdk.Asset('USD', source.publicKey());
  let rate_converted = parseFloat(rate).toFixed(7);
  let total_amt = parseFloat(amt).toFixed(7);
  let buyPrice =  parseFloat (1 / rate_converted).toFixed(7) ;

  if(cutDown){
    buyPrice = parseFloat(buyPrice - 1.5).toFixed(7);
    }
  let op ={
    selling: USD,
    buying:  StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
    amount: total_amt+"",
    price: buyPrice+"",
    offerId:0 
  }

 return server.loadAccount(client.publicKey())
    .then(function(account) {
      var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(account)
        .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.manageOffer(op))
        .setTimeout(10000)
        .build();
      transaction.sign(StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(client.secret()));
      return server.submitTransaction(transaction);

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err.response.data);
      return err.response.data.extras.result_codes; 
    });

}
```

What does op_cross_self actually mean? And also each time offer ID is `0`.

Comment: If you indeed want to accept the offer you created, you should use a different account to post the second offer.

Answer (score 3):

It is the `MANAGE_OFFER_CROSS_SELF` error described in the [guides](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#manage-offer) and it prevents you from unintentionally fullfilling your own previous offer:

> The account has opposite offer of equal or lesser price active, so the account creating this offer would immediately cross itself.

You should have a look at [passive offers](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#create-passive-offer) for this case.